# Is there a function in Haskell to group the elements of a list in the following way?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a list [0,1,2,3] and I want a new list with elements [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]. Is there a function to do this in Haskell?

Comment: I don't think there's any such function provided in the standard libraries - but it's easy to implement yourself. Hint: you'll need to use `zip`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Brilliant! Thanks!! I figured it out. I could just drop the first element of the list and zip it with its original self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it work with `zip` where you pass it both the list, and the tail of that list. For example with pattern matching:

```
f :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
f [] = []
f xa@(_:xs) = zip xa xs
```

or with [**`tail :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail):

```
f :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
f xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

the above will work, even for empty lists, since the `zip` will first pattern match on the first list, if that list is exhausted, it will not look at the second list.

Or in applicative style:

```
f :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
f = zip <*> tail
```